# Don't output specific category on entry page

Tags: entries, categories

With

```
{% for category in entry.categories.all() %}
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a> {{ not loop.last ? '| ' }}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I exclude a specific category from displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but you *can* just insert an `if` block into your loop:

```
{% set excludedId = 1234 %}

{% for category in entry.categories.all() %}
  {% if category.id != excludedId %}
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
    {{ not loop.last ? '|' }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That said, this will no longer know whether the "last" item in the loop was excluded. A better solution might be to trim down the collection *before* beginning the iteration:

```
{% set excludedId = 1234 %}

{% for category in entry.categories.all() | filter((c) => c.id != excludedId) %}
  <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
  {{ not loop.last ? '|' }}
{% endfor %}
```

This makes use of the [`filter` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html), which you can pass a "function" of sorts to compare each ID to your excluded one. If the comparison is `false`, it'll remove it from the collection before the loop starts.

One last option (and possibly the best one) is to adjust the query itself, before it's run:

```
{% set excludedId = 1234 %}
{% set onlyDesiredCategories = entry.categories.id("not #{excludedId}").all() %}

{% for category in onlyDesiredCategories %}
  <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
  {{ not loop.last ? '|' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of filtering down from the natural relations, this method attempts to adjust the [`ElementQuery` instance provided by the relation field](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/69faaee88ab6b797fe8fb95e2c525271f4f094ef/src/fields/BaseRelationField.php#L354-L411) (`entry.categories`) by setting the `id` param to `not 1234`, meaning that ID will be excluded when the query is executed. *I haven't actually tried this lat method, myself, so your mileage may vary.*

Comment: #3 worked for me! Thanks very much.